# Custom cells into a scroll view vs. using Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a list like Facebook's news feed,There are so much news from my users and I have to show them like Facebook does.

First I create an NSObject class for generating each cell's object. Then I create a UIViewController that is initialized with this object class. This controller is each object's cell.

```
-(id)initWithNewsObject:(NewsObject *)new Delegate:(id)delegate{
self=[super init];

if(self)
{

    _delegate=delegate;

    _new=[[NewsObject alloc]initWithNewsObject:new];


}
return self;}
```

So I create the news list using for loop in my main View Controller.

**Here is my question,Which one of list structure ensures the best performance ? Listing the cells with for loop or using TableView ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hands down **Table View**.

Table view will show/hide/recreate cells only when it needs and from device to device, it will handle those automagically. If you even attempt to do this for your own ScrollView, you will have to cater for different device sizes and resolutions and orientations.

If you don't do this for your own ScrollView, you will have a lot of views just sitting in the memory, not a very good choice.

And even if you do all these successfully, congratulations, you have just reinvented the wheel, you have just created your own MyTableView instead of `UITableView`.

Comment: So what is the limit of scrollView? if I have 20 textFields(not more than that) for registration, is it ok to go with scroll view?

Comment: There isn't a limit on scrollview. It will just become slower to load or scroll, depending on what you are loading in scrollview. If I had 20 similar looking items, I would use tableview.

Answer (score 1):

Tableview will be MUCH better since you don't have to manually manage scrollView's content size and especially if you don't need any pinch to zoom or horizontal panning support. Tableview also has some nifty lazy loading built in so you don't have to manage the memory for all of the objects you load on the screen as well.

I think using a tableView with variable cell sizes or custom cells is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Table View.

Imagine that users continue scrolling for hundreds of your "cells." You'll have to manually manage the memory for hundreds of view controllers vs. iOS handling them via the dequeue method in table view.

It automatically recycles cells for you and you can make the content size different based on what type of cell it is (image, text, video, etc).